# Constructing Romberg integration table

Tags: math, fortran, gfortran, numerical-integration, numerical-analysis

I am trying to write a Fortran program to generate a Romberg integration table. There's an algorithm in the book **Numerical Analysis by R.L.Burden and J.D.Faires 9th ed.** in chapter 4.5. So far I have written this

```
implicit none
integer,parameter::n=4
real::a,b,f,r(n,n),h,sum1
integer::i,k,j,m,l
open(1,file='out.txt')
a=0.
b=1.
h=b-a
r(1,1)=.5*h*(f(a)+f(b))
write(1,*)r(1,1)
do i=2,n
    sum1=0.
    do k=1,2**(i-2)
        sum1=sum1+f(a+(k-.5)*h)
    enddo
    r(2,1)=.5*(r(1,1)+h*sum1)
    do j=2,i
        r(2,j)=r(2,j-1)+(r(2,j-1)-r(1,j-1))/(4**(j-1)-1)
        write(1,*)((r(m,l),m=2,2),l=1,i)
    enddo
    h=h/2.
    do j=1,i
        r(1,j)=r(2,j)
    enddo
enddo

end

real function f(x)
implicit none
real,intent(in)::x

f=1/(1+x**2)

end function
```

This program gives the following output:

```
  0.750000000    
  0.774999976      0.783333302    
  0.782794118      0.785392165       3.56011134E-22
  0.782794118      0.785392165      0.785529435    
  0.784747124      0.785398126      0.785529435       7.30006976E+28
  0.784747124      0.785398126      0.785398543       7.30006976E+28
  0.784747124      0.785398126      0.785398543      0.785396457
```

But it is supposed to give this:

```
0.7500000000 
0.7750000000 0.7833333333 
0.7827941176 0.7853921567 0.7855294120 
0.7847471236 0.7853981253 0.7853985227 0.7853964451 
0.7852354030 0.7853981627 0.7853981647 0.7853981590 0.7853981659
```

The above one is done by a program written in Maple. The program in Maple is

```
>   romberg := proc(f::algebraic, a, b, N,print_table) 
 local R,h,k,row,col; 
 R := array(0..N,0..N); 

 # Compute column 0, Trapezoid Rule approximations of 
 #                   1,2,4,8,..2^N subintervals 
 h := evalf(b - a); 
 R[0,0] := evalf(h/2 * (f(a)+f(b))); 
 for row from 1 to N do; 
   h := h/2; 
   R[row,0] := evalf(0.5*R[row-1,0] + 
                     sum(h*f(a+(2*k-1)*h),k=1..2^(row-1))); 
   # Compute [row,1]:[row,row], via Richardson extrapolation 
   for col from 1 to row do; 
     R[row,col] := ((4^col)*R[row,col-1] - R[row-1,col-1]) / 
                       (4^col - 1); 
   end do; 
 end do; 

 # Display results if requested 
 if (print_table) then 
       for row from 0 to N do; 
     for col from 0 to row do; 
       printf("%12.10f ",R[row,col]); 
     end do; 
     printf("\n"); 
   end do; 
 end if; 

 return(R[N,N]); 

end proc:
f:=x->1/(1+x^2);
val:=romberg(f,0,1,4,true)
```

So now what to do with the Fortran program to get the same result as found by Maple program?

Comment: Hi, use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention. The version tags, like fortran90, should not be used without the generic one.

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of differences between the maple program and the fortran source.

- The result array of the maple program is dimensioned from 0 to n, while the Fortran program runs from 1 to n.
- The Fortran source never defines (calculates a value for) r(3:,:) on account of fixed column indices.

Given those differences, it shouldn't be surprising that the results differ.

A naive, relatively direct, translation of the maple source into F2008 gives the same result, after accounting for the usual vagaries of floating point arithmetic.

```
module romberg_module
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: rk = kind(1.0d0)

  abstract interface
    function f_interface(x)
      import :: rk
      implicit none
      real(rk), intent(in) :: x
      real(rk) :: f_interface
    end function f_interface
  end interface
contains
  function romberg(f, a, b, n) result(r)
    procedure(f_interface) :: f
    real(rk), intent(in) :: a
    real(rk), intent(in) :: b
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real(rk) :: r(0:n,0:n)    ! function result.

    real(rk) :: h
    integer :: row
    integer :: col
    integer :: k

    h = b - a
    r(0,0) = h / 2 * (f(a) + f(b))
    do row = 1, n
      h = h / 2
      r(row, 0) = 0.5_rk * r(row-1, 0)  &
          + sum(h * [(f(a + (2 * k - 1) * h), k = 1, 2**(row-1))])
      do col = 1, row
        r(row, col) = (4**col * r(row, col-1) - r(row-1, col-1))  &
            / (4**col - 1)
      end do
    end do
  end function romberg

  subroutine print_table(unit, r)
    integer, intent(in) :: unit
    real(rk), intent(in) :: r(0:,0:)
    integer :: row
    do row = 0, ubound(r,1)
      write (unit, "(*(F13.10,1X))") r(row, :row)
    end do
  end subroutine print_table
end module romberg_module

program print_romberg_table
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: output_unit
  use romberg_module
  implicit none
  real(rk), allocatable :: r(:,:)
  r = romberg(f, 0.0_rk, 1.0_rk, 4)
  call print_table(output_unit, r)
contains
  function f(x)
    real(rk), intent(in) :: x
    real(rk) :: f
    f = 1.0_rk / (1.0_rk + x**2)
  end function f
end program print_romberg_table
```

Comment: How to write it in Fortran90 ?

Comment: Move and rename the interface block to be a non-abstract local interface for the dummy procedure and replace the procedure statement, remodel the format specification in the write statement, preallocate (and post-deallocate) the variable in the main program that receives the result of calling the romberg function, make the internal function `f` a module procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is too long to be debugged just by reading the code (and it's more than 5 years I don't write a single line of f95), but from your result table it is evident that in F90 real variables are represented as single precision (32 bit) IEEE 754 floating point numbers, while maple uses higher precision.

In fact to 32 bit precision 0.775 becomes (approx) 0.77499998, while to 64 bit it is 0.77500000000000002. <strike>The completely wrong numbers (e.g. 3.56011134E-22) could be due to underflow/overflow, or cancellation.</strike>

You can force 64 bit precision with suitable compiler options, or by specifying the appropriate real kind, see http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Real+precision

```
integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
real(kind=dp) :: a
```

Comment: As the excellent [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32303228/1499402) by @ianh demonstrates, I was just to lazy to carefully read the program: precision cannot explain the bad results. However I'm not deleting this answer because the remark about precision may be still useful.